# Java | JPA | How to combine Multiple repetitive Annotations into Single Annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

In Following JPA Code i have around 20 fields for which i need to create 20 tables in element collection.

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = JtcaTab.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "JTCA_MATERIAL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "trackingId"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "company",column = @Column(name = "company")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "orderDate",column = @Column(name = "orderDate")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "estimateDate",column = @Column(name = "estimateDate")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "cost",column = @Column(name = "cost")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "hours",column = @Column(name = "hours")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "quantityRun",column = @Column(name = "quantityRun")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "quantityScrapped",column = @Column(name = "quantityScrapped")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "quantityReject",column = @Column(name = "quantityReject")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "blankQty",column = @Column(name = "blankQty")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "certificateNumber",column = @Column(name = "certificateNumber")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "certificatePath",column = @Column(name = "certificatePath")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "comments",column = @Column(name = "comments")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user",column = @Column(name = "user")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "completed",column = @Column(name = "completed")),
    })
    private List<JtcaTab> jtcaMaterial;
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = JtcaTab.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "JTCA_CUTOFF", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "trackingId"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "company",column = @Column(name = "company")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "orderDate",column = @Column(name = "orderDate")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "estimateDate",column = @Column(name = "estimateDate")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "cost",column = @Column(name = "cost")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "hours",column = @Column(name = "hours")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "quantityRun",column = @Column(name = "quantityRun")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "quantityScrapped",column = @Column(name = "quantityScrapped")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "quantityReject",column = @Column(name = "quantityReject")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "blankQty",column = @Column(name = "blankQty")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "certificateNumber",column = @Column(name = "certificateNumber")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "certificatePath",column = @Column(name = "certificatePath")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "comments",column = @Column(name = "comments")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user",column = @Column(name = "user")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "completed",column = @Column(name = "completed")),
    })
    private List<JtcaTab> jtcaCutoff;

    .
```

If you see above the annotation set is common with only difference in Collection Table Name.
As this repeat 20 times.

Is there any way to create a common set of all above annotations an mention minimal set in entities?

Comment: I understand you're asking about JPA's support for meta annotations? Nope, sorry, no such luck. I'm not sure I follow, though: you need to **override** the defaults for 20 uses of `JtcaTab`, all in the same manner? If the overrides are to be used 20 times, why not make **them** defaults?

Comment: @crizzis: i dont understand

Comment: Let me rephrase: from what I understood, you're asking if you can create an annotation that will group those repeated `@AttributeOverride`s, so that you can use that annotation instead of the current fourteen. The answer to that question is: no, it's not possible with JPA

Comment: My other question is: why do you need those `@AttributeOverride`s in the first place? What is the default column name for, say, `JtcaTab.company` that you're trying to override? And why isn't the default column for `JtcaTab.company` simply `company` if you say the column is going to be named `company` in 20 tables?

Comment: @crizzis: I do not understand actually. For creating table without @Id; i have used this approach earlier. i.e to Create a bean and just add it in attribute overrides in element collection and it works fine. What are other way to notating same field?

Comment: Open the `JtcaTab` class. Does `JtcaTab.company` have a `@Column` annotation? If so, what is the value of `@Column.name`?